# best practice for using session values on a search page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am using MVC5 to build an application and have a question regarding the use of session values.

I have a report that have 2 date pickers, and 3 dropdown lists. None are mandatory.

What I need to do is ensure that if the user picks something from the list, runs the report and then goes off to the detail page (an action link that take to another view), when they come back on the return to report link their search is intact.

Also, if they hit F5 on the page, their search parameters remain.

Ok, so I have a controller action

```
     public ActionResult ClaimReport(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, int staffId = 0, int teamId = 0, int vehicleId = 0)
```

This action has a load of variables passed in to it, that form the basis of the search. When ever the search button is pressed, I call the ClaimReport method from my view and pass all of the chosen values from the dropdowns and datepickers to this method for me then to filter the results at the database..

I then do this:

```
        var sessionSearch = Session["searchParams"] as staffList;

        //No previous search exists - create an empty session
        if(sessionSearch == null)
        {
            sessionSearch = new staffList{
            teamId =0,
            fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
            toDate = DateTime.Now,
            vehicleId = 0,
            staffId =0};
        }
        //A previous search has been submitted - update the session
        else
        {
            sessionSearch.teamId = teamId;
            sessionSearch.fromDate = fromDate;
            sessionSearch.toDate = toDate;
            sessionSearch.vehicleId = vehicleId;
            sessionSearch.staffId = suId;
        }
```

The theory here is that if no session exists, I create a new empty search - otherwise I take what is already in the session.

I then perform all of my database stuff before finally doing this:

```
        Session["searchParams"] = sessionSearch;    
        return View(report.ToList());
```

This saves the parameters back to the session and returns my report back to the screen as a view.

This works for the first call to the method, but if I hit F5 the page reloads and the method ClaimReport is loaded again, but obviously all of parameters for the method are back to defaults as they haven't been grabbed from the view due to the way the page has loaded.

The session still exists, but it is overwritten by what is now effectively a blank search.

Can anyone help me on how I can improve what is happening here? I feel I am missing something obvious..

Manythanks

Comment: `This works for the first call to the method, but if I hit F5 the page reloads and the method ClaimReport is loaded again` -- Which is why I always just save such things to the model.

Comment: So if I take my model (I.e. database object) and then create a view model with that object and my search prams that might work?  I don't need to store those values in the db do I?

Comment: You've got to store them somewhere.  How else is the application going to remember them when you need to retrieve them?

Comment: How do I then tie that to one session?  I.e  so only that one session gets those parameters applied to the page?

Comment: Track it by user and page.

Comment: Sounds fair.  Thank you I will give it a go.